# Unity3d: What class should audio processes or calculations be called in?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am creating an audio-visualizer that reacts to amplitude using the Unity5 game engine. I calculate the amplitudes using logarithms, RMS values and .GetOutputData.

Initially I had my function called from the Update class but its reaction time was too slow and the visualizer appeared to be out of synchronization with the music. I am now calling my function from the OnGUI class, but it is still not a real-time reaction to the music.

When or how should I call my function to get the best audio visualization in real-time? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you for your assistance.

My Visualization Function:

```
void OnGUI () 
{
    //PROCESS AMPLITUDE:
    /***/
    ///RETRIEVE THE AUDIO-SOURCE SAMPLES:
    //Declare and Initialize an array to store the samples;
    float[] samples = new float[iSamples];
    //Pass the samples' array to the audio-source;
    auTheCurrentSong.GetOutputData (samples, 0);

    ///CALCULATE THE RMS VOLTAGE VALUE:
    //Declare and Initialize the sum of the squared samples;
    float fTotalSquaredSamples = 0.0f;
    //FOR each sample in the samples' array...
    for (int counter=0; counter < iSamples; counter++) {
        //... Calculate the sum of the squared samples;
        fTotalSquaredSamples += Mathf.Pow (samples [counter], 2);
    }
    //Calculate the average or mean of the total squared samples;
    float fMeanSquaredSamples = fTotalSquaredSamples/iSamples;
    //Calc  ulate the root mean square (RMS) value;
    float fRMS = Mathf.Sqrt (fMeanSquaredSamples);

    //CALCULATE THE DECIBEL VALUE FOR OUTPUT:
    //Calculate the decibel value;
    float fdBValue = 20*Mathf.Log10(fRMS/fReference);
    //Clamp dB values:
    //IF dB values are less than -160...
    if (fdBValue < -160)
    {
        //...Clamp dB values to -160;
        fdBValue = -160;
    }

    //RESPOND TO PRODUCT:
    //Debug the decibel values to check for irregularities;
    Debug.Log (fdBValue);

    //Scale a 3-D cube vertically depending on the dB value;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1.0f, fdBValue, 0.0f);
    /***/
}
```

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Comment: I am working on multiple projects at the moment and don't have time to give attention to this specific one right now. AND Because I can not delete or hide this question temporarily you will just have to wait until I can come back to this thread with feedback.In the mean time if you have the same problem see if any of the answers work for you and then if you want you can share your results. :) Otherwise just be patient.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to rescale the cube right before it is rendered, so that you have the smallest possible latency between "measuring" amplitude and displaying the result. Have a look at [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) from the Unity Manual, further down the page is a flowchart that explains when each function is called on a MonoBehaviour. As you can see, OnPreRender() is the last function that is called before the scene is being rendered, so I would try putting your code there. If that doesn't work, try the function before that and so on.

Comment: Thank you I shall return with my progress asap.

Answer (score 0):

What per-frame-method you execute your calculation or visualization code in does not matter really.
You can use anything from Update to LateUpdate, OnPreRender, OnPostRender, as they are all called every frame, with practically no measurable time difference.

If your visualization seems to be lagging behind the currently playing audio output, there are several possibilities:

1. You are mistaken and the visualization is actually correct
2. Visualization is wrong, you are accidentally mirroring it or something like that
3. The visualization is correct, but the data it visualizes has been incorrectly calculated
4. Data, calculation and visualization are correct, but the data you fetch using GetOutputData is outdated.
5. Your framerate is just so low (~5 fps) that there really is a noticable time difference between the currently playing audio and the result of the visualization. Debug.Log() is very (!!) slow if you use it per frame.

Comment: Thank you I shall return with my progress asap.